# Selenium. Python. Не могу получить содержимое тега

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, по какой причине не получаю содержимое тега в данном случае.
Сайт: https://b2c.passport.rt.ru/ - Раздел Регистрация

Сначала пытаюсь понять верный ли раздел:

```
page_name = pytest.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
page_name = page_name.text
assert page_name == 'Регистрация'
```

Данный код успешно выполняется.

Далее пытаюсь понять внутри тега Региона всегда ли Москва г:

```
field_region = pytest.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-right"]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/span[1]/span[1]')
field_region = field_region.text
assert field_region == 'Москва г'
```

И вот уже этот код не работает: **AssertionError: assert '' == 'Москва г'**
Почему пустое значение? Ведь этот тег точно содержит название региона.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В итоге удалось найти ответ на собственный вопрос. Проблема оказалась в том, что родительский элемент имел css-свойство display: none.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно было ему изменить свойство и тест заработает:

```
field_region = pytest.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                               '//*[@id="page-right"]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/span[1]')
pytest.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", field_region)
field_region = pytest.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                              '//*[@id="page-right"]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/span[1]/span[1]')
field_region = field_region.text
assert field_region == 'Москва г'
```